# What is GA version of Azure Form Recognizer?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-cognitive-services, azure-form-recognizer

I need Indonesian language support but I'm a bit confused what the GA version is.

I got it using the following link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/applied-ai-services/form-recognizer/language-support

See screenshot:-

[image]

Comment: GA - Generally Available. In other words, production version.

Comment: Hi @GauravMantri you mean any latest version of FR. Currently FRv.3 is the latest. But, it has no support for Indonesian language. But the documentation mentions that the GA version of the FR has Indonesian language support.

Comment: Latest version need not always mean the GA version.

Comment: @GauravMantri So what is the current GA version of Azure FR. Through which I will be able to use Indonesian language support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, I got it.
Here I found it:-

[image]